# How to validate input which was atribbuted in the Typescript code?

Tags: angular, validation

I have an input HTML field which receives a date. When this happens, it activates the validation control on the field and I get an error if the date is incorrect. 
Now I need to set some value I am getting from Firestore to this input and I am using

`(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).value = value`

to do this. It works well but the value is not recognized by the validator. I want to know how can I implement it. I am using angular 7 and angular form validators. The validator works perfectly when getting the value from UI.

I've tried to use function setError from the form control, attributing null to it, but for my code, this is not efficient. I've also tried to trigger DOM events in typescript because I think it is the way it occurs in the UI.

Comment: You can use the `reportValidity()` method of `form` object to trigger validation manually (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity)

Comment: Don't touch the DOM directly with Angular. Re-read this https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to access the DOM in Angular. If you want reference use ElementRef, to manipulate you want Renderer2. However, here you don't need either.

Simply patch the value

```
this.form.patchValue({
    'date': value
});
```

Sometimes you may not want to emit an event when you update values

```
this.form.controls['date'].patchValue(dateData, { emitEvent: false });
```

You may need this to manually check validity on all fields

```
Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
  this.form.get(key).markAsDirty();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, use `@ViewChild` to access to the input element, probably that's the first fault because the DOM access.
Later, when gathering the data from firebase, set the value to the referred input element and emit that the value has changed using `ngModel` (https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#valueChanges)

Comment: I didnt comment above but I've already tried this. The fact is that I can't use ngModel inside a formGroup anymore. @ViewChild also doesn't work because I am getting the values from a ngFor loop and I haven't found a way to pass template variables with a specific index. I guess there is none. Anyway thanks for helping.